# XAMPP Port changes so frequent. Every second

Tags: php, xampp, phpstorm

I have a issue with my XAMPP, PhpStorm. No idea what is the reason, I am not an expert. Please advise if you have any idea.

My PHP projects on my local host was working fine till yesterday night. But today morning it stopped working.

It's working on my server. When I checked my XAMPP the port number is 63342 at start. It was like that for several months. And it's constant for all the time. But now when I try to run a project on PhpStorm then my XAMPP ports starts fluctuating so frequent. It keeps on changing so fast. Every second new port number showing. It's only happens when PhpStorm project is started.

Is it the issue with PhpStorm or XAMPP? I am new. If I reinstall XAMPP will it be fine? Or is it with the issue with my PhpStorm.

My PhpMyadmin is working fine even when the port number changes. I don't want to do any thing with out an expert opinion. I am not sure what the problem is.

Comment: Sounds like some process (most likely the http server) crashes and is restarted immediately by some watch dog process. The port is not (yet) freed again which is why the process selects some other port. So you need to find out what crashes and why it does. The first place to _always_ start debugging with such a setup is the http servers log files, then the system log files.

Comment: *"When I checked my XAMPP the port number is 63342 at start."* What? `63342` is a standard port used by PhpStorm/WebStorm and other JetBrains IDEs -- it's used by built-in web server and other services. It cannot be used by XAMPP. It's possible that all this time you were using PhpStorm web server and not XAMPP... which should be using standard port `80` and/or 8080. **In any case:** Have you tried restarting your computer? It may resolve it.

Comment: I am new.I see on XAMPP its Main port 63342.Now its working.I changed my PHP port like its told here.https://phpmysqllearners.wordpress.com/2014/01/27/changing-phpxampp-port-number-in-xampp/

Comment: In my case, it made xdebug, when I opening other links to XAMPP, like phpMyAdmin. Property - "Force break at first line when no path mapping specified"

Answer (score 0):

I guess any other software or application is using the port . 
Check on your xampp configuration file check for port and change it . To check which app is using the port go to task manager for windows and check for port.
If helps you can reinstall the xampp
Try checking port numbers in task manager and change the port in the conf file of xampp

Comment: I changed my port number but still when I start  php storm it starts changing again.

Comment: Then i gues your php storm is using the same port which is wierd. So try reinstalling

Comment: First time my project works.Like load the first page.But then the port on xampp changes and then onwards project dont work.

Comment: reinstall xampp?

Comment: XAMPP has several PID in task Manger but PHP storm has only one.

Comment: Yeah try reinstall

Comment: It now working.I changed the php port like   https://phpmysqllearners.wordpress.com/2014/01/27/changing-phpxampp-port-number-in-xampp/

Comment: Actually I don't really know what I am doing thats the problem.Thanks